# Elasticsearch query to find duplicate values of one field and return the value of another like GROUP BY

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch 6.4 - given an index with documents with a field called `CaptureId` and a field called `SourceId`: we need to search for duplicate records by `CaptureId` value. The `SourceId` field can have many records with the same value, and we want to return only one `SourceId` per set of duplicates found.  So the output would be a list of `SourceIds` (listed only one time each) which contain any number of duplicate `CaptureId` values.

How would I create this query in ElasticSearch?

Here is the document mapping:

```
"mappings": {
            "fla_doc": {
                "_field_names": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "properties": {
                
                    "captureId": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "capturedDateTime": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "language": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "sourceId": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "sourceListType": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "region": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both of these ID fields are of the [`keyword` data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html), you could do the following:

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_duplicate_capture": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CaptureId",
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_underlying_source_ids": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "SourceId",
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In case you're interested in more `SourceIDs`, increase the `size` param.

Comment: Thanks for this - I have run this and it doesn't seem to be doing the Group By functionality.  For example, the first several documents returned have CaptureId 1, 2, 3 etc and all of them have SourceId 1.  Assuming SourceId 1 is the only SourceId with any duplicate CaptureIds, I would want to only be returned one document with a value of SourceId 1.

Comment: Can you share a few of your docs + the mapping?

Comment: Thanks for your continued help, Joe.  I've updated my post with the mapping.  I will have to get with one of my devs to get a few example docs.  In the meantime, just imagine that if I have 6 documents, and the first 3 all have captureId 10 and sourceId 1, and the other 3 all have captureId 20 and sourceId 2, I would want the query to return sourceid 1 and 2.

Comment: Right -- that's exactly what the query from above returns. Here's the explanation: https://prnt.sc/w0pgg7 So a bit of aggregation post processing will be required to get to a simple list of source IDs but all the info you need is in there..

Comment: Joe - find here the exact query I'm running and the exact response I'm getting: 10 documents, all with different captureId's and the same sourceId. https://filebin.net/k10x30phdfd3l0ki  What am I missing here?

Comment: Oh I see now. So you'd like to de-duplicate those too? Because what the response is telling me is that there are lots of non-unique capture ids that tend to happen in the same session(s) -- there seem to be always 2 session IDs but the query is returning only one. So what you could do is set a high `size` attribute in the `CaptureId` aggregation and then increase the nested agg's `size` to 2 and then concatenate and de-duplicate the resulting 2-member lists. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not on first read, lol, but I'm certainly going to try it and make it make sense!  I'll be back with an update asap.